# Thread Result shown in text area

Tags: java, multithreading, swing

I want to execute a thread, and it should get some result after specific interval of time. Now I want to show that result in `JTextArea`. How to make an event from thread for `JTextArea`?

Comment: have a look at [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2710712/output-to-jtextarea-in-realtime), this will also solve your problem.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This depends on how you established you're background task.

If you're using a plain `Thread` or `Runnable`, you need to fire an event onto the Event Dispatching Thread (ETD) that will ensure that any changes you make to the UI occur within in the EDT.

Swing provides a simple mechanism that allows you to enqueue a `Runnable` onto the event queue, whose `run` method will be executed within the EDT.

```
// Inside you thread...
// Some block action...

SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
    public void run() {
        // Executing within the EDT...
    }
});
```

Take a look at

- [Concurrency in Swing](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/concurrency/index.html)
- [Swing Utilities#invokeLater](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/swing/SwingUtilities.html#invokeLater%28java.lang.Runnable%29)

A simpler solution might be to use a `SwingWorker` instead of a plain `Thread`.  This will allow you to take action on the completion of the worker within in `done` method (which is executed for you within the EDT)

Take a look at

- [Worker Threads and SwingWorker](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/concurrency/worker.html)
- [SwingWorker](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/swing/SwingWorker.html)