# set text while being inside a loop

Tags: java, swing

i'm building an e-mail client and i have some issues, i want to "append" a "Sent + email " in a jTextArea, all is good and the code is working. 
however, it only drops the " Sent + email " after the for loop is finished ..

code:

```
    for (int i = 0; i < to.length; i++) {
        int count = i;

        if (!emailValidator.validate(to[i].toString().trim())) {
            System.out.print("Invalid Email ID++");
            jTextAreaStatus.append("Invalid Email:\t" + to[i] + "\n");
            jLabelFail.setText("| F: " + String.valueOf(i + 1));
        } else {

            new SendMail().StartSend(smtpHostName, smtpUserName, smtpPassword, fromEmail, fromName,
                    to[i], body, subject, smtpPort, smtpSSL, smtpAuth);

            // show the sending count
            jTextAreaStatus.append("Sent:\t" + to[i] + "\n");
            jLabelCount.setText("S: " + (i + 1) + " / " + String.valueOf(to.length));

            if (isCanceled) {
                break;
            }

        }
    }
```

what am i doing wrong ?

thanks!

PS: i'm using swing for the gui.

Comment: I think there is a similar issue that you should look into here:
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2710712/output-to-jtextarea-in-realtime

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If this loop is running on the main thread, the UI will only be refreshed once the process is complete. If you place this process into a separate thread, you UI should refresh during the process. Otherwise, there should be a command to refresh the UI during a process that you can call during every iteration of your loop.

[UPDATE] To answer your comment this is how to start a thread in java:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
   Thread thead = new Thread(new myRunner());
   thread.start();
}



public class myRunner implements Runnable {

      @Override
      public void run() {
         // Do this in the background -- your for loop goes here
      }

 }
```

In this example I am starting a new Thread and running it in the background. The Thread takes in an implementation of the Runnable class and will execute the run method in the background.

Once the thread has started, your main method will continue to execute. If you want to wait for the thread to finish before continuing you can use `thread.join();` after `thread.start();` and the calling thread will wait at that point for the thread to complete before continuing.

If you want to learn more about threading I would suggest you have a look at http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/concurrency/

Just be careful when using thread, thread can create more problems them they are worth because you need to start making you application thread safe: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/concurrency/

Good luck!

Comment: Thanks! Thats what i was missing